# Struts 2 jquery plugin upgrade

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery

Due to vulnerabilities we have upgraded our Struts version from 2.1.8 to 2.3.34. struts2-jquery-plugin also upgraded from 1.4 to 3.x.

Problem is `<sj:select>` tag was not working properly and dropdown values are not displaying.

Can any let me know any changes required for `<sj:select>` after upgrade.

```
<sj:select id="TransactionID" 
           name="customerSearchVo.transactionID" 
           value="%{customerSearchVo.transactionID}" 
           onChangeTopics="onChangeEntityTopic" 
           indicatorId="entityLoadingIndicator" 
           list="#session.entityLst">
</sj:select>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr,Thank you for your response. Please check below code<sj:select id="TransactionID"
name="customerSearchVo.transactionID" value="%{customerSearchVo.transactionID}"
onChangeTopics="onChangeEntityTopic"
indicatorId="entityLoadingIndicator"
list="#session.entityLst">
    </sj:select>

Comment: Hi,Can any one pls help me on the above issue.

Comment: Any errors? Why do you use `sj` select here?